# Function doesn't execute in script

Tags: shell-script

I created this script called ShellScript.sh, and in this script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Shell script 

function help {
  echo ""
  echo "./ShellScript.sh {start | stat}"
  echo ""
  echo "These are some commands:"
  echo ""

  # Start command
  echo "start"
  echo "This starts the process"
  echo ""

  # Stat command
  echo "stat"
  echo " abcxyz"
  echo ""
}
```

However, on the command line, when I type "./ShellScript.sh help", nothing happens. I've been trying to figure out this problem for a day now and am sure I'm missing something small but I don't know what it is!

Comment: Everything your script does is does defining `help` function, you need to add something more.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk add something more like what though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear what your final goal is, but calling `./ShellScript.sh help` passes the *parameter* "help" to the script; as Arkadiusz Drabczyk commented, all that ShellScript.sh is doing is setting up a function, then exiting.

It appears as though you are building up an option-driven script to start or stat a process, in which case you need some "main"-level code to parse the parameters and call the function(s).

For example, add this to the end of your ShellScript.sh:

```
case "$1" in
start)
    echo "This starts the process"
    ;;
stat)
    echo "stat"
    echo " abcxyz"
    ;;
help)
    help
    ;;
*)
    echo "usage: $0 start|stat"
    ;;
esac
```

As a suggestion, "stat" is really similar (to humans) to "start"; consider "status" instead?

Comment: This helped me solve my problem! Thanks a lot for your suggestion on using status too. Only started using shell scripting 2 days ago so I'm relatively new to all this

Answer (score 0):

You've defined a function, but you haven't actually done anything with it. You'd need to *call* that function in the script. If this is working towards a more general approach where you want to call one of several functions depending on the argument to your script, simply make it this (I've just shown part of it, adding `$`` at the end):

```
    # Stat command
    echo "stat"
    echo " abcxyz"
    echo ""
}

$1
```